# How to get last Friday of month(s) using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I have a function that returns me only the fridays from a range of dates

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime startDate, int weeks)
{
    int days = weeks * 7;

    //Get the whole date range 
    List<DateTime> dtFulldateRange = Enumerable.Range(-days, days).Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i)).ToList();

    //Get only the fridays from the date range
    List<DateTime> dtOnlyFridays = (from dtFridays in dtFulldateRange
                                    where dtFridays.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday
                                    select dtFridays).ToList();
    return dtOnlyFridays;
}
```

**Purpose of the function:** "List of dates from the Week number specified till the StartDate i.e. If startdate is 23rd April, 2010 and the week number is 1,then the program should return the dates from 16th April, 2010 till the startddate".

I am calling the function as:

```
DateTime StartDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact("20100430", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
List<DateTime> dtList = Utility.GetDates(StartDate1, 4).ToList();
```

Now the requirement has changed a bit. I need to find out only the last Fridays of every month. 
The input to the function will remain same.

Comment: @Newbie: the version of C# is important, but also the version of .NET, since C# by itself can't help you - you need the .NET Framework.

Comment: A more idiomatic implementation would use `IEnumerable<DateTime>` instead of converting everything to a `List<DateTime>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the list of Fridays in the given range. Now just query this again like this:

```
List<DateTime> lastFridays = (from day in fridays
                              where day.AddDays(7).Month != day.Month
                              select day).ToList<DateTime>();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Just a small improvement on Sarath's answer, for those (like me) who step into this question

```
private DateTime GetLastFridayOfTheMonth(DateTime date)
{
    var lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));

    while (lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
        lastDayOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(-1);

    return lastDayOfMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an extension method we are using.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime GetLastFridayInMonth(this DateTime date)
    {
        var firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
        int vector = (((int)firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek + 1) % 7) + 1;
        return firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(-vector);
    }
}
```

Below is the MbUnit test case

```
[TestFixture]
public class DateTimeExtensionTests
{
  [Test]
  [Row(1, 2011, "2011-01-28")]
  [Row(2, 2011, "2011-02-25")]
  ...
  [Row(11, 2011, "2011-11-25")]
  [Row(12, 2011, "2011-12-30")]
  [Row(1, 2012, "2012-01-27")]
  [Row(2, 2012, "2012-02-24")]
  ...
  [Row(11, 2012, "2012-11-30")]
  [Row(12, 2012, "2012-12-28")]

  public void Test_GetLastFridayInMonth(int month, int year, string expectedDate)
  {
    var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    var expectedValue = DateTime.Parse(expectedDate);

    while (date.Month == month)
    {
      var result = date.GetLastFridayInMonth();
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, result);
      date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on DeBorges answer, here is an extension to get any specific Day

```
public static DateTime GetLastSpecificDayOfTheMonth(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayofweek)
    {
        var lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));

        while (lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek != dayofweek)
            lastDayOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(-1);

        return lastDayOfMonth;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what day of the week the first day of the next month is on, then subtract enough days to get a Friday.

Or, if you already have a list of Fridays, return only those for which adding 7 days gives a date in the next month.

Answer (score -1):

Call the below function by sending the date as parameter, in which it extracts the month and year from the date parameter and returns the last `Friday` of that month

```
public DateTime GetLastFridayOfMonth(DateTime dt)
{
      DateTime dtMaxValue = DateTime.MaxValue;
      DateTime dtLastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));

      while (dtMaxValue == DateTime.MaxValue)
      {
           // Returns if the decremented day is the fisrt Friday from last(ie our last Friday)
           if (dtMaxValue == DateTime.MaxValue && dtLastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
               return dtLastDayOfMonth;
           // Decrements last day by one
           else
              dtLastDayOfMonth = dtLastDayOfMonth.AddDays(-1.0);
      }
      return dtLastDayOfMonth;
}
```

Comment: Why use DateTime.MaxValue here?

Comment: @ColinM It seems to be used as a constant. It's the same as doing `while (true) { ... }`, although seems very clunky. It also contains an unnecessary check whether the value has changed.