# Check if this Monday is last Monday in a month

Tags: c#

I use  this code from another question:

```
private bool NthDayOfMonth(DateTime date, DayOfWeek dow, int n){
  int d = date.Day;
  return date.DayOfWeek == dow && (d-1)/7 == (n-1);
}
```

It works fine.  But it not checks a last day ( for me it's when n = 5). How to modify it?
Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711357/how-to-get-last-friday-of-months-using-net

Comment: Please give an example where it doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method below checks the given date is the last date of week of month.

```
private bool IsLastOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    var oneWeekAfter = date.AddDays(7);
    return oneWeekAfter.Month != date.Month;
}
```

So there is new method, it just checks mondays

```
private bool IsLastMonday(DateTime date)
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) 
        return false; // it is not monday

    // the next monday is...
    var oneWeekAfter = date.AddDays(7);

    // and is it in same month?, if it is, that means its not last monday
    return oneWeekAfter.Month != date.Month;
}
```

Comment: i added a new method for just checks monday.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take March 30,

```
d = 30,  
(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) == true, 
(30-1)=29, 29/7 = 4
4 == (5-1)
```

So it works

To only check if DayOfWeek  is last in mothth you can use

```
return date.AddDays(7).Month != date.Month;
```