# Need a query to display employee payment date.?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

```
EMP:

EMPNO   ENAME   JOB         MGR     HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782    01/23/1982  1300     -      10
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    12/17/1980  800      -      20
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    02/22/1981  1250    500     30
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    09/28/1981  1250    1400    30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    05/01/1981  2850     -      30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    06/09/1981  2450     -      10
7839    KING    PRESIDENT    -      11/17/1981  5000     -      10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    09/08/1981  1500     -      30
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    02/20/1981  1600    300     30
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    04/02/1981  2975     -      20
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    12/09/1982  3000     -      20
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788    01/12/1983  1100     -      20
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698    12/03/1981  950      -      30
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    12/03/1981  3000     -      20
```

If Emp's hired on or before 15th of any month are paid on the last Friday of that month, those who hired after 15th are paid on the first Friday of the following month. Print a list of emps along with their hire date and pay date.

In oracle We can achieve this with simple query. Can any one suggest me simple SQL Server query to display the required result.

Here is the below code i tried in SQL server,

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN DATEPART(DD,HIREDATE)<=15 
            THEN (CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='MONDAY' 
            THEN DATEADD(DD,-4,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='TUESDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,-3,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='WEDNESDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,-5,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='THURSDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,-6,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='FRIDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='SATURDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,-1,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='SUNDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,-2,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            END)
    ELSE CASE
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='MONDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,2,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='TUESDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,4,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='WEDNESDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,3,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='THURSDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,1,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='FRIDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,0,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='SATURDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,6,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))='SUNDAY'
            THEN DATEADD(DD,5,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,HIREDATE))))
        END
    END
FROM EMP;
```

The above query is working as expected, But i am searching for a simple way to achieve this..... :)

Comment: Before receiving any help we need to see what you have first tried.

Comment: Hi @RaduGheorghiu check out my query

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you want the results this should be enough to get you going. The [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [DAY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) TSQL statements will help you achieve your outcome.

```
SELECT
    [EmpNo], 
    [EName], 
    [HireDate], 
    CASE 
        WHEN DAY([HireDate]) <= 15 THEN 'Last Friday'
        ELSE 'First Friday' 
    END AS 'PayDate'
FROM EMP
```

Comment: We should display the PayDate base on hiredate and using the criteria they mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something you can sanely do in SQL Server.  If insane is OK to you, check out [this example](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic762485-1608-3.aspx#bm770150) which uses various `dateadd`, `datediff` and `%` operations.

A slightly better option is a client language like C#, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5715728/50552).  Still on the other side of sanity.

At the end of the day, doing payroll in Oracle is just easier.  You can use [`next_day()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/next_day.php):

```
select  next_day(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), 'FRIDAY') as first_friday
,       next_day(last_day(sysdate)-7, 'FRIDAY') as last_friday
from    dual
```

Which is still not as easy as it could be, but easier than anything you could do in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE A FUNCTION**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_FirstLastFriday(@Year INT)
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS 
-- First and Last Friday
RETURN 
(select min(dates) as [First Friday], max(dates) as [Last Friday] from
(
select dateadd(day,number-1,DATEADD(year,@year-1900,0))
as dates from master..spt_values
where type='p' and number between 1 and
DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(year,@year-1900,0),DATEADD(year,@year-1900+1,0))
) as t
where DATENAME(weekday,dates)='friday'
group by DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0,dates),0))
```

**Test Table**

```
DECLARE @EMP TABLE (EMPNO INT,ENAME VARCHAR(20),JOB VARCHAR(20)
               ,MGR INT, HIREDATE DATE, SAL INT,COMM INT, DEPTNO INT)
INSERT INTO @EMP
VALUES
(7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,'01/23/1982',1300, NULL,10),
(7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,'12/17/1980',800,NULL,20),
(7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'02/22/1981',1250,500,30)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN DAY(E.HIREDATE) >= 1 AND DAY(E.HIREDATE) <= 15 THEN T.[Last Friday]
                ELSE T.[First Friday] END AS Friday
FROM @EMP E
       CROSS APPLY 
               dbo.fn_FirstLastFriday(YEAR(E.HIREDATE)) T
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═══════╦══════╦════════════╦══════╦══════╦════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ EMPNO ║ ENAME  ║  JOB  ║ MGR  ║  HIREDATE  ║ SAL  ║ COMM ║ DEPTNO ║      First Friday       ║       Last Friday       ║         Friday          ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═══════╬══════╬════════════╬══════╬══════╬════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  7934 ║ MILLER ║ CLERK ║ 7782 ║ 1982-01-23 ║ 1300 ║ NULL ║     10 ║ 1982-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-01-29 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║  7934 ║ MILLER ║ CLERK ║ 7782 ║ 1982-01-23 ║ 1300 ║ NULL ║     10 ║ 1982-02-05 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-02-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-02-05 00:00:00.000 ║
║  7934 ║ MILLER ║ CLERK ║ 7782 ║ 1982-01-23 ║ 1300 ║ NULL ║     10 ║ 1982-03-05 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-03-26 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-03-05 00:00:00.000 ║
║  7934 ║ MILLER ║ CLERK ║ 7782 ║ 1982-01-23 ║ 1300 ║ NULL ║     10 ║ 1982-04-02 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-04-30 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-04-02 00:00:00.000 ║
║  7934 ║ MILLER ║ CLERK ║ 7782 ║ 1982-01-23 ║ 1300 ║ NULL ║     10 ║ 1982-05-07 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-05-28 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-05-07 00:00:00.000 ║
║  7934 ║ MILLER ║ CLERK ║ 7782 ║ 1982-01-23 ║ 1300 ║ NULL ║     10 ║ 1982-06-04 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-06-25 00:00:00.000 ║ 1982-06-04 00:00:00.000 ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═══════╩══════╩════════════╩══════╩══════╩════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

**Note**

> I have added both 1st and last friday In my answer for only Demo
>   pupose, But you can exclude these columns from your answer and only
>   use the last column [Friday] for which I have used a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE,
 CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(HIREDATE,'DD')<=15 
 THEN NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(HIREDATE)-7,'FRI')
 ELSE NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_months(HIREDATE,1))-7,'FRI')
 END "payDATE"
 FROM EMP;
```