# Is there a specific function that will return whether or not a given date in is the last full week of the curent month

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

There are plenty of ways to determine the week number or the day of the week of a given date.  I would like to create a routine in my application that does some routine housekeeping work on the last Friday of the month (which may or may not equate to is this Friday in the last full week of the current month).

I have in mind some pseudo code along these lines;

```
If AreWeOnTheFridayOfLastFullWeekOfTheMonth Then
    <carry out housekeeping here>
End if


Private Function AreWeOnTheFridayOfLastFullWeekOfTheMonth

        Dim dte As Date = Today

       If dte.DayOfWeek.ToString = "Friday" Then
        If <dte is in the last full week of the current month > then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End

End Sub
```

Does anyone know if there is such a function secreted in the various dot net assemblies (I haven't come across one yet in various variations of google or bing searches on First or last full week of current month) or of a way to determine it.

Whilst I'm using vb it doesn't matter if the answer is in c# with the obvious proviso that it uses functions and methods common to both languages.

Edit

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711357/how-to-get-last-friday-of-months-using-net) question.  I'm wondering is there is a simpler way to determine simply if we are in the last Full week of the current month.

Thanks

Edit 2:

Just thought I would add vb translations of the above two neat example given by Jeppe Stig Nielsen  Note that I have substituted Today for the date parameter in each case meaning that you can just call the function and get a Boolean return based on whatever day it is that you call it.

```
Public Function TodayIsTheLastFridayOfTheLastFullWeekOfTheMonth() As Boolean
    Dim daysLeftInMonth  As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Today.Year, Today.Month) - Today.Day
    Return Today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday AndAlso 8 > daysLeftInMonth AndAlso daysLeftInMonth >= 1
End Function

Public Function IsTodayWithinTheLastFullWeek() As Boolean
    Dim dayOfWeekAsInt As Integer = CInt(Today.DayOfWeek) ' take more care here if 'first' day-of-week is not defined as Sunday
    Dim dateOfBeginningOfWeek As Date = Today.AddDays(-dayOfWeekAsInt)
    Dim daysLeftInMonth As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Year, dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Month) - dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Day
    Return 13 > daysLeftInMonth AndAlso daysLeftInMonth >= 6
End Function
```

EDIT3

and from the final comment that Jeppe made in relation to the first full week of the current month;

```
Public Function IsTodayWithinTheFirstFullWeek() As Boolean
        Dim dayOfWeekAsInt As Integer = CInt(Today.DayOfWeek)
        Dim dateOfBeginningOfWeek As Date = Today.AddDays(-dayOfWeekAsInt)
        Return dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Day <= 7
    End Function
```

Comment: Specify _last full week_. What if the last friday is in a week with 6 days? Show some examples including edge cases.

Comment: Do you consider a full week to be Sunday through Saturday, Monday through Sunday, Saturday through Friday, Monday through Friday, or other?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If we take last week as an example ( and I'm thinking of a week beginning on Sunday and ending on Saturday)  it straddled June and July. So had my pseudo function been called on Friday the 26th of June it would have returned true as that would have been the last full week of the current month.

Comment: @DomSinclair but if you want the last Friday of the month, do you really care whether Saturday is the first of the next month?

Comment: "which may or may not equate to is this Friday in the last full week of the current month" So you do not care if it is last full week?

Comment: From the 'housekeeping' point of view that I wish to carry out on the last Friday,  those of you who have pointed out that whether it is actually in the last 'full' week is largely irrelevant are correct, but it would still be nice to know if there is an easy way to determine if a day is in the last full week (or indeed the first full week) of the current month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last Friday in a month you can use this:

```
Public Function GetLastFridayInMonth(ByVal aDate As Date) As Date
    Dim firstDayOfNextMonth = (New Date(aDate.Year, aDate.Month, 1)).AddMonths(1)
    Dim delta As Integer = ((CInt(firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek) + 1) Mod 7) + 1
    Return firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(-delta)
End Function
```

If you want the last Friday of the month were that Friday falls in a complete week then you need to define what the complete week means as there are different interpretations. Is that all days of the week fall in the month (which day is the start/end of the week) or is it 4/7 of the days fall in that week?

Comment: Can't fault that Matt , a nice example and certainly easy enough to allow me to determine if indeed it's the last Friday of the month. So given that I had said Friday in my question This is a correct answer and I've market it as such...Thanks.    Still love to know if there's a way to determine if we're in the last full week(Sunday- Saturday) of the current month though could be very useful for other things and presumably with a little tweaking could be applied to the first full week of the current month as well.

Answer (score 2):

In C#:

```
static bool IsLastFriday()
{
  var date = DateTime.Today; // can be made a parameter

  return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && date.Day + 7 > DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
}
```

---

I should have read your question more carefully. Here is a solution in C#:

```
static bool IsFridayOfLastFullWeek()
{
  var date = DateTime.Today; // can be made a parameter

  var daysLeftInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month) - date.Day;

  return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday
    && 8 > daysLeftInMonth && daysLeftInMonth >= 1;
}
```

The bounds 8 and 1 assume your "full week" goes from Sunday through Saturday. They can be changed to e.g. 9 and 2 respectively if your week notion is different.

---

If this should work not just for Fridays (I saw your comment to the other answer), go with:

```
static bool IsWithingLastFullWeek()
{
  var date = DateTime.Today; // can be made a parameter

  var dayOfWeekAsInt = (int)(date.DayOfWeek); // take more care here if 'first' day-of-week is not defined as Sunday
  var dateOfBeginningOfWeek = date.AddDays(-dayOfWeekAsInt);
  var daysLeftInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Year, dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Month)
    - dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Day;
  return 13 > daysLeftInMonth && daysLeftInMonth >= 6;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful answers definitely a plus 1.  Just as a matter of interest if in your last example (and again assuming Sunday as the start of a week) we were searching for the first full week would it simply be a matter of altering the two integers (13 and 6 ) in your return statement?

Comment: @DomSinclair First week of the month could be easier since we do not have the issue that months end on different dates (like 31st, 30th, or 28th/29th) because of their unequal lengths. Taken from the "start side" every month looks the same. So try with this: `static bool IsWithingFirstFullWeek()
    {
      var date = DateTime.Today;

      var dayOfWeekAsInt = (int)(date.DayOfWeek);
      var dateOfBeginningOfWeek = date.AddDays(-dayOfWeekAsInt);
      return dateOfBeginningOfWeek.Day <= 7;
    }`