# Last Day Of The month

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

I'm writing a method that returns the last saturday of the month

```
    public static DateTime LastDayOfTheMOnth(DateTime Date)
```

I don't know how to start, in java is simple but in c# is more dificult

Comment: Get the last day of the month and subtract the difference between its weekday number and the Thursday's weekday number?

Comment: Just replace `Friday` with `Thursday` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34792820/5514820).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a month to the current day and go backwards from there.
Taken from [here](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Last_Friday_of_each_month#C.23).
I've made it as an extension method so that you can call it from the `DateTime`object itself.

```
public static DateTime LastThursday(this DateTime time)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Thursday) {
        date = date.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return date;
}
```

Can be called like

```
DateTime x = new DateTime(2019, 4, 22);
Console.WriteLine(x.LastThursday());
```

Comment: You immediately know how much to subtract from the very first `date.DayOfWeek`. There is no need for a loop.

Comment: No, this doesn't work if the last day of the month is earlier than a Thursday. Use the september of 2019 as an example `DateTime time = new DateTime(2019, 9, 22);` It would return 27.09.2019 for your approach - which is wrong - and 26.09.2019 for the loop version - which is right.

Comment: `It would return 27.09.2019 for your approach` - why?

Comment: Could be that I misunderstood you but you're saying that `return date.AddDays(date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Thursday);` should work as well, given that `date` is defined like in my answer. That returns `27.09.2019` for `DateTime(2019, 9, 22)`.

Comment: No, I said that `date.DayOfWeek` is already enough to calculate the number of days to subtract, without a loop. I was also talking about distance between days of week rather than about difference between numeric values of the members of the `DayOfWeek` enum, which is important because `Sunday` is unfortunately zero. So you have to do something like `int days_to_subtract = ((((int)date.DayOfWeek + 1) % 7 + 2) % 7);`. It's a somewhat obscure expression and it can be easily replaced with a couple of `? :` operators, but in any case you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get list of Saturday in specific month

```
 var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

        for (int day = daysInMonth; day > 0; day--)
        {
            DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            if (currentDateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                list.Add(currentDateTime);
            }
       }
```

secondly, use linq to get last Saturday from the list

```
 var result = list.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).First();
       Console.WriteLine(result);
```

> note: you can change `DayOfWeek.Saturday` to any day you want

Working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/silLhk)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
    public static DateTime LastThursdayOfTheMonth(int month, int year)
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, year));
        while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(-1);
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Regards, LA.